# Can I use ajax/getJson() to grab local variable json arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For usable code wireframing, I almost never have a db/data source to begin with, and subsequently throw a bunch of json arrays into a *.js file and call to them from each object/grid/etc.. to populate screens until the data modelling/db creation is complete.

How would/could I write an ajax/getJson() function to get the correct flat variable array from said *.js file? Calling to a *.json file is trivial:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '*.json',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

..but what do I do for separate arrays, for example:

```
data.js

var fakeData = [{
    "programName": "Art Blakey",
    "programGroup": "Jazz Messengers",
}];

var moreFakeData = [{
    "programName": "Joe Dart",
    "programGroup": "Vulfpeck",
}];
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the variables are in .js files AJAX is a bit redundant - you can just include the .js in the page with another `<script>` tag

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He said he's just doing this for wireframing during development. In the real application it will be a dynamic script.

Comment: When you assign objects to variables in a JavaScript file, it is not JSON, but a JavaScript. There is no such thing as a `JSON array`: you either have text in JSON, or you have a JavaScript array.

Comment: The goal of where I'm trying to go here is to be able to walk away from the code with only trivial modification so the other devs have a usable ajax function. I want one include, 'fakedata.js' that only needs to be removed (to keep mess/touching the code to an absolute minimum) once the other developers are binding to db data. BTW, that's also what I thought on getScript! I do like the idea of just throwing all the fake data in a single JSON structure, but that seems like it will be a mess to manage; I like being able to mockup some data in excel, export as csv, convert to JSON and walk away.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only data, you could make it a JSON object that holds the different arrays and use your working approach:

```
{
    "fakeData": [{
        "programName": "Art Blakey",
        "programGroup": "Jazz Messengers",
    }],
    "moreFakeData": [{
        "programName": "Joe Dart",
        "programGroup": "Vulfpeck",
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please just call it JSON, not "JSON object".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$.ajax`, you could use `$.getScript`, and have it return a `.js` file rather than JSON. Then it will simply execute the Javascript that's returned, and the variable assignments will be executed.

A disadvantage of this method is that it forces you to use global variables and ties the client and server side to specific variable names. This isn't as flexible as using JSON.